# How to install OpenCV 3.0.0 and 2.4?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, opencv

I know that a lot of questions have been posted regarding the installation of OpenCV, but right now I need to install both **OpenCV 2.4** along with **OpenCV 3.0.0**

Since there are a lot of research codes available online and the authors of these say that our code is not compatible with OpenCV 3.0.0, I am wondering how can I install both versions of OpenCV.

Even before the installation instructions, can somebody please tell me how to remove all the existing versions of OpenCV from my PC. I want to do a clean installation of OpenCV, with appropriate setting of all the environment variables.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run command: `sudo apt-get remove opencv.`

This will uninstall the opencv and then delete the opencv folder from home, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Only gives you one at a time;
You can compile both versions, and keep the compiled code in the build folders. When you want to use a specific version, run `sudo make -j 4 install` in that build folder.

Answer (score 0):

To **uninstall OpenCV**, you have 2 options depending on how you installed it:

1. If you installed it with apt-get, run: `sudo apt-get remove opencv.`
2. If you compiled it by your own, I think it was something like `(sudo) make uninstall` in the directory where you did `make` and `make install` (usually `build/`).

Both will uninstall OpenCV (in the later case it will still leave you the local folder you used to compile it, so you can re-compile or re-install it at any moment).

To **install both OpenCV versions**. I dumb trick I did was to prepare 2 OpenCV compilation folders (one for each version). And then a bash script program that performs `make uninstall` on one folder and `make install` on the other one. It should take it ~15 seconds to switch the OpenCV version on this way, since both version will be already locally compiled.